# Force blocking database offline during SET OFFLINE

Tags: sql-server, database

I need to take a database offline immediately, but a latent connection is blocking the `SET OFFLINE` operation. I attempted to take it offline from SQL Server Management Studio, which would have called `ALTER DATABASE <database_name> SET OFFLINE`, instead of `ALTER DATABASE <database_name> SET OFFLINE WITH NO-WAIT` like I should have.

Other attempts to access or take the database offline fail because a lock a cannot be obtained due to the blocking operation.

How can I cancel the blocking `SET OFFLINE` operation without taking my entire instance offline?

---

**Update:** I ended up restarting my SQL Service instance, which quickly released the lock, but it was undesirable. I would still like to know how to kill the connections blocking a `SET OFFLINE` operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't cancel the offline command: it will wait until it can od it's thing.

You can [KILL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173730.aspx) the offending connection though.

You *may* be able to kill the ALTER DATABASE statement but IIRC it's already executed.

If you restart SQL Server the DB will be offline too.

Comment: How do I KILL an offending connection?

Comment: @FreshCode: added a link to the KILL above. You find the connection ID (SPID) from sys.sysprocesses

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is execute the following sql:

```
USE MASTER
ALTER DATABASE <database_name> SET SINGLE_USER  with rollback immediate
```

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180141/what-sql-is-required-to-put-sql-server-2005-in-single-user-mode) for further info / links

Comment: I know how to force a database offline now, but I'm trying to solve my initial mistake while the blocking operation is still in place. Running that command throws "ALTER DATABASE failed because a lock could not be placed on database '<database_name>'. Try again later.
ALTER DATABASE statement failed."